Can't get products from whatsapp catalog when the app is running on cloud
I have created a whatsapp app with catalog integration. When a user places an order the product details are fetched using
url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{product_catalog_id}/products"
params = {
    "fields": '["category","name","description"]',
    'filter': f'{{"retailer_id": {{"i_contains": "{retailer_id}"}}}}',
    "summary": "false",
    "access_token": access_token
}

It works when I am running it using ngrok, but when I use aapanel, for some reason, this same script returns null there. I have tried hardcoding the value of product_catalog_id to test if thats the issue. But nothing works, and its also not throwing any error. What could be the reason? Am I lacking any permissions?
